# come across with Kubernetes Deployment Problem with

Tags: kubernetes

During the deployment of my application to Kubernetes, I come across with such kind of problem :

```
Waiting for deployment "yourapplication" rollout to finish: 0 of 1 updated 
replicas are available...
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
Waiting for deployment "yourapplication" rollout to finish: 1 out of 2 new 
replicas have been updated...
Waiting for deployment "yourapplication" rollout to finish: 1 out of 2 new 
replicas have been updated...
Waiting for deployment "yourapplication" rollout to finish: 0 of 2 updated 
replicas are available...
```

Also I get that error message as well :

```
**2019-06-13T12:01:41.0216723Z error: deployment "yourapplication" exceeded 
its progress deadline 
2019-06-13T12:01:41.0382482Z ##[error]error: deployment "yourapplication" 
exceeded its progress deadline
2019-06-13T12:01:41.0396315Z ##[error]/usr/local/bin/kubectl failed with 
return code: 1
2019-06-13T12:01:41.0399786Z ##[section]Finishing: kubectl rollout
**
```

Answer (score 3):

> **2019-06-13T12:01:41.0216723Z error: deployment "yourapplication" exceeded 
>   its progress deadline 
>   2019-06-13T12:01:41.0382482Z ##[error]error: deployment "yourapplication" 
>   exceeded its progress deadline

You can try increasing progress deadline of your deployment:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#progress-deadline-seconds

Comment: Hello Anton. I increased it in the deployment.yaml file such like that : spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 60000 .. But it still keeps waiting .

Comment: Could there be something wrong with the deployment? For example cluster access to container registry and it's unable to pull the containers. How does it look like, if you do ``kubectl describe deploy/DEPLOYMENT_NAME``

Comment: @AntonAhlroth I am also facing the same issue but in my case, my pod is running but not in ready state, so I am stuck in vicious circle as we have issue in this image so we are upgrading to new image but new image deployment stuck in exceeded its progress deadline ...so any idea how to come out of this loop